# Convert string to JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json

How do I convert string to object? I am facing this problem because I am trying to read the elements in the JSON string using "each".

My string is given below.

```
jsonObj = "{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}"
```

I have used `eval` and I have used

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);
```

And i have also used

```
var obj= eval("(" + jsonObj + ")");
```

But it comes null all the time

Comment: have you tried single quotes? `'{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}'`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object?rq=1

Answer (score 70):

Enclose the string in single quote it should work. Try this.

```
var jsonObj = '{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/d34WN/)**

Comment: Thanks @ShankarSangoli. "$.parseJSON()" works fine. I was trying with "parseJSON()" which didn't really help.

Answer (score 18):

Combining [Saurabh Chandra Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1371778/saurabh-chandra-patel)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25882886/3991344) with [Molecular Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842075/molecular-man)'s [observation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165021/3991344), you should have something like this:

```
JSON.parse('{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}');
```

Answer (score 11):

try:

```
var myjson = '{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}';
var newJ= $.parseJSON(myjson);
    alert(newJ.TeamList[0].teamname);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code `$.parseJSON(myjson)` . It is really work.

Answer (score 4):

Your string is not valid. Double quots cannot be inside double quotes. You should escape them:

```
"{\"TeamList\" : [{\"teamid\" : \"1\",\"teamname\" : \"Barcelona\"}]}"
```

or use single quotes and double quotes

```
'{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}'
```

Answer (score 4):

only with  js

```
   JSON.parse(jsonObj);
```

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer, this eval work:

```
eval('var obj = {"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Without eval:

Your original string was not an actual string.

```
jsonObj = "{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}"
```

The easiest way to to wrap it all with a single quote.

```
 jsonObj = '"{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}"'
```

Then you can combine two steps to parse it to JSON:

```
 $.parseJSON(jsonObj.slice(1,-1))
```