# jQuery template issue with JSON data

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-templates

I'm using jQuery templating which is taking JSON data to create a table. This code is working fine. But when I try to create a function around this code and pass JSON data to it which I'm getting from an AJAX request, it shows the values in the console but not in the table. Working code with dummy data is:

```
var json = [{"class":12,"marks":"500","marks1":"200","marks2":"300"},{"class":11,"marks":"200","marks1":"300","marks2":"400"}]

$.template('kList','<tr title="${class}"><td>${marks}</td><td>${marks1}</td><td>${marks2}</td></tr>');  

for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){   
    $.tmpl('kList',json[i]).appendTo("#table1")
}
```

Here is the code where I'm warping the upper code in function and passing the JSON data as a parameter that shows the values in console when I print it with `console.log(json)` but not filling the table. The JSON parameter is having the same JSON data as in above code.

```
function dataTable(json){
    console.log(json); // here json values are appearing in the console
    $.template('kList','<tr title="${class}"><td>${marks}</td><td>${marks1}</td><td>${marks2}</td></tr>');  

    for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){   
        $.tmpl('kList',json[i]).appendTo("#table1")
    }
}
```

Please help me out because I don't know whats wrong in this code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `json` parameter is a string. You should convert it to an object, using `$.parseJSON`(json).

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164944/convert-string-to-json-object) for conversion detail.

Comment: It is Giving me a response on console as [Object, Object] and i have already used $.parseJSON(json) so the parameter json is the output after using $.parseJSON(json). do you have any other suggestions or do you find anything else wrong in this code?

Comment: @Sau: So check if `json[0].class` has value and feedback.

Comment: i have tried console.log(json[0].class); and in console its showing me undefined but when i do console.log(json[0]); then it shows all values. can you make this code work i'll be really thankful to you

Comment: @Sau: Ithink there is something wrong with your json. I don't know what do you mean of " then it shows all values". Write the log.

Comment: @Sau: Regarding your string of json in first part of your answer, I ran a test here, take a look and compare strings of json: http://jsfiddle.net/oliol/zWJeu/

Comment: I am able to figure it out. you are correct the problem. you are right the problem was with the json. Thanks for your great help..