# Getting error while Convert string to json object

Tags: javascript, json

```js
var result = "";
result += "[";
for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
  {
    result += "{ 'key': 'keyvalue" + i + "', 'values': [";
    for(j=0;j<=10;j++)
      {
        result += "{ 'key': 'subkeyvalue"+j+"', 'value':"+j+"}, ";
      }
    result += "]}, ";
  }

result += "]";

console.log(result);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(JSON.parse(result));
```

If i try to convert String to JSON.parse. I am getting below error.

JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 4 of the JSON data

can you please any one resolve this problem.

Comment: Wrap _keys_ and _values_ in double quotes

Comment: BTW why you are doing this? As you can do the same with `JSON.stringify` passing JavaScript object;

Comment: why you are creating string ? make proper object and add to array and then use JSON.stringify() to make json string

Comment: @Tushar said **Wrap keys and values in double quotes** not in single;

Comment: after converting string to JSON object i need to create chart

Comment: you can try something like this.

var stringtojson = JSON.stringify(result);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to JSON Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164944/convert-string-to-json-object)

Comment: You can pass JavaScript object to charts JavaScript methods no need of encoding and decoding here;

Comment: try using the mapping function. a utility lib like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) takes a lot of the pain of of stuff like this

Comment: i don't know mapping function. how i will use mapping. i tried JSON.stringify but its not happening. again its showing same string format values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't create JSON strings manually** through string concatenation. Just...don't.

Create an array, create appropriate objects and add them to the array, then pass the array to your charting library as is.

Or if you actually need a JSON *string* use `JSON.stringify()` on the array.

And note that [there is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

```js
var result = [];
var vals;
for(var i=0;i<=10;i++) {
  vals = [];
  for(j=0;j<=10;j++) {
    vals.push( { key: 'subkeyvalue'+j, value: j } );
  }
  result.push( { key: 'keyvalue' + i, values: vals } );
}

// someChartFunction(result);

console.log(result);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet `( result += "]}, ";) , ","` (comma) is getting appended at the last, so the json will be like `"},]"` where you will be expecting like `"}]"`

Comment: You should add this in comment as this is not a complete answer;

Comment: May be `result += '{ "key": "subkeyvalue'+j+'", "value":'+j+'}, ';` then is this statement is correct?

Comment: based on my requirement result is coming. but its coming string format

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `JSON.stringify()` or use key and value in (') quote

```
var result = "";
result += "[";
for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
  {
    result += "{ 'key': 'keyvalue" + i + "', 'values': [";
    for(j=0;j<=10;j++)
      {
        result += "{ 'key': 'subkeyvalue"+j+"', 'value':"+j+"}, ";
      }
    result += "]}, ";
  }

result += "]";

console.log(result);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: i tried JsON.stringify again it showing same string format result

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code given below. You should not append the , (Comma) to the last element while iterating

```js
var result = "";
result += "[";
for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
  {
    result += '{ "key": "keyvalue' + i + '", "values": [';
    for(j=0;j<=10;j++)
      {
        result += '{ "key": "subkeyvalue'+j+'", "value":'+j+'}';
        if(j!=10) {
          result += ','
        }
      }
    result += ']} ';
    if(i!=10) {
     result += ','
    }
  }

result += ']';

console.log(result);

console.log(JSON.parse(result));
```